# can't find pinvoke dll dbnetlib.dll error on ce 5.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, pinvoke, windows-ce

i'm deploying an app for ce 5.0 that connect to a sql server 2008 into a server:
i've installed in the ce sql.wce5.armv4i.CAB and sql.dev.ENU.wce5.armv4i.CAB, but when I try to connect to the database appears the error:

```
can't find pinvoke dll dbnetlib.dll
```

how can I solve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That DLL appears to be the "[Super Socket Net Lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174500%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)" and is probably part of a full-framework solution, though I'm not sure what distributes it.  It doesn't matter for the context of this question where it comes from because the fact you see the error tells me that you're probably using some desktop component or reference in your Compact Framework solution, which will not work.  You can only use CF assemblies, so whatever is trying to use dbnetlib.dll must be removed from the project.

Comment: i'm using not sqlcompact, cause i need to connect to sql server 2008 and I use sqlconnection class

Comment: Reworded my answer. Regardless, you cannot use *any* desktop assemblies and you must be referencing something that's pulling in dbnetlib.dll.  You have to remove that reference and use a supported mechanism for talking to the datbase (SqlClient, etc).

Comment: thanks, and how can I make queries without sqlclient (used the dll of compact framework 3.5)?

Comment: You *can* use SqlClient, but you have to use the CF version.  Just make sure you added only CF references to your project.

Comment: thanks again...I've added SqlClient... is this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\Client\System.Data.SqlClient.dll, 'cause the CF doesn't have SqlClient.dll

Comment: You should be adding it from the .NET references, not browsing. I just verified it's there in two of my dev environments.